# Hover on dropdown menu

Tags: list, drop-down-menu, hover, nav

http://www.funky7inc.com/product/detroit-police

if you hover over the area where the dropdown is on "Detroit Apparel" the list pops up instead of only appearing when you hover over the nav.

any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you only change the opacity of that `<ul class="sub-menu">`... So it is actually always there, only 100% seethrough... But you can still hover over it which changes the opacity back to fully visible.

I don't know how you change this (CSS:hover of Javascript or something, I tried looking but you have minified CSS) but you can solve this by not changing just the opacity but also the display:block to display:none so it is actually gone, or use javascript $(".sub-menu").hide() or .FadeIn()/fadeOut() or something similar...

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are changing the opacity of the drop down list. **Opacity:0** still registers mouse over event.

Instead use **visibility** property or **display:none**

When you will hide the drop down using visibility or display:none, drop down list would not register mouse over and hence the list would not show up till the time hover is on the navigation bar.

Hope this helps.